# Deploying node.js application on Ubuntu VPS

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, node.js, socket

I created an real time android application backed by a node.js application. I use express, socket.io, mongodb and ubuntu for my backend. But my problem is on how I can possibly run it in production or over the web alone without me running this `node server.js` in a remote commandline accessing my server. Because when I stop it, my application will become unavailable. Also, I meed to access it directly to my domain or IP without adding the port `:3000` on it. Is this possible?

I tried to do this https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-express-a-node-js-framework-and-set-up-socket-io-on-a-vps but I need to be on my commandline in order for it to run always. I heard of using nginx as proxy server but I have no idea on how to configure it with node.js

Comment: You mean like the related tutorial that was at the bottom of that page?

Comment: Thanks for informing me. I haven't seen it. But, is it applicable only for one vps instance?